# Postgres and Ruby's Sequel: Empty array in where-clause getting converted to slow query

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using the excellent Sequel ORM, and at some point I've generated an array of IDs and I'm trying to retrieve the users that have those IDs. e.g.

```
user_ids = [1, 2, 3]
User.where(id: user_ids).all
# (0.004223s) SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("id" IN (1, 2, 3))
```

But sometimes, the list of users is empty, and what I effectively get is this:

```
User.where(id: []).all
# (0.421287s) SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("id" != "id")
```

The result is correct (i.e. no rows returned), but the query is two orders of magnitude slower.

On tables with millions of rows, it can take a couple of seconds to return.

I'm curious why this query is generated in the first place, but I'm also curious why the Postgres query planner doesn't seem to detect this contradiction and return an empty dataset instantly.

Is there a neat solution to this, or will I have to check all arrays for emptiness?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0, Sequel 4.24.0 & Postgres 9.3.6.

Comment: You don't need to add `all` to retrieved all users

Comment: @GaganGami I do if I want to execute the query and see the time it took to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [closed issue on github](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/1025) about this behavior.

I agree with jeremyevans that there is no need for a fix, because it is obvious that the reseult will and should always be empty. Furthermore you would agrue that PostgreSQL should be clever enough to optimize queries like that and should not do a whole table scan.

Therefore it makes way more sense IMHO to fix this behavior in the code to avoid to call the database completely:

```
user_ids.present? ? User.where(id: user_ids) : []
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. It also explains why just `false` isn't used instead of `id != id`. (Although I can't think of a scenario when it would occur)

Comment: with recent versions of rails you can write:

`user_ids.present? ? User.where(id: user_ids) : User.none`

in this way you return an active record relation everytime

Answer (score 1):

Note that Sequel's default behavior was changed in 4.25.0 so that such queries will use `false` instead of `id != id`. While `id != id` may be more correct in terms of NULL handling, the performance benefits of `false` make it a better default.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Just updated to 4.28.0 - didn't realise I was so far behind. In what scenario does using `1 = 0` fail?